# Prime Push not working after migrating to 6.2

Tags: primefaces, atmosphere

I have an app that uses Primefaces.
It was on version 6.0 and everything was working fine.

Now I'm trying to update the Primefaces version to 6.2 and my websockets stop working.
I updated the Atmosphere dependency to version 2.4.6 as the manual says.
However I keep getting this message:

Websocket closed, reason: Connection was closed abnormally (that is, with no close frame being sent). - wasClean: true

And then my messages are not delivered;
Is anyone else with this problem?

Comment: What is your jsf version? Updated that too?

Comment: I'm using JSF 2.2